# Unity Canvas hover image does not trigger event

Tags: unity, c#, gui

So i have the following setup:

[image]

This produces the following UI:

[image]

Now on each of the "HudCircle"(Bottom/Right/Left/Top), I have the following components:

[image]

As you can see I have a script that has the following code:

```
    public class HUDAction : MonoBehaviour,  IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public Color StartColor;
    public Color SelectedColor;
    public Image Image;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Image = GetComponent<Image>();
        StartColor = Image.color;
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Image.color = SelectedColor;
        Debug.Log("Over");
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Image.color = StartColor;
        Debug.Log("Not over");
    }
}
```

Sadly when playing this scene nothing happens when I hover either of the circles.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image component needs to have the Raycast Target checkbox checked. I assume you have an EventSystem GameObject somewhere in the hierarchy to handle sending the events as well. If not, you’ll need one of those too.